# return bool value with two reduce inside each other js

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const find = haystack => search.toLowerCase().split(/\s/)
   .reduce((f, c) => {haystack.split(/\s/).reduce((w, a) => w || a.toLowerCase().startsWith(c)), false}, false)
```

here I need to get a `bool` from this function, when the haystack value only consist of one word like "matchedValue" it was quite ok to do with one `reduce()`, but when I have the haystack value like "match value" and I wanna filter the results even when the search value match the second part of the field I needed two `reduce()` but it seems I am missing something

Comment: What are the conditions for the boolean exactly?

Comment: so the case is 
I have a search term let's say "test", and I have haystack, when the haystack starts with "test" the filter is working
like search = 'test'
haystack= 'test me' 
this fine when I have this function 
```
const find = haystack => search.toLowerCase().split(/\s/)
      .reduce((f, c) => f || haystack.toLowerCase().startsWith(c), false)
```

but if the haystack = 'me test'
search = 'test' that function is not working anymore
because it takes the haystack as one string

Comment: So you want to check if your haystack string has a word e.g. "test" in it or not?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const find = (queryString,token) => queryString.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).includes(token);

console.log(find("test me","test"));
console.log(find("me test","test"));
```

Comment: Thank you, 
the point includes is very strict it is like `===`
I want something to filter when the string starts with some characters it doesn't have to match entirely

Answer (score 0):

```
const find = (haystack, search) => {
      search = search.toLowerCase().split(/\s/)
      haystack = haystack.toLowerCase().split(/\s/)

      return search.some(searchTerm => {
        return haystack.some(haystackTerm => {
          return haystackTerm.startsWith(searchTerm)
        })
      })
    }
```

Thanks everyone tried to help, I found this way and it worked for me